Counting valid Permutations with Directional Movement Constraints
This is a spin off from this Leetcode question when I was thinking of potential follow ups 2337. Move Pieces to Obtain a String
To quote the first part of it

You are given two strings start and target, both of length n. Each string consists only of the characters 'L', 'R', and '_' where:
The characters 'L' and 'R' represent pieces, where a piece 'L' can move to the left only if there is a blank space directly to its left, and a piece 'R' can move to the right only if there is a blank space directly to its right.
The character '_' represents a blank space that can be occupied by any of the 'L' or 'R' pieces.

The question ahead basically asks given two strings, start and target, can you make target from start?
This can be solved by a program checking the positions of L's and R's and checking if they maintain their relative order and move only in their allowed directions. (among many other approaches)
I was thinking can we count the possible target strings we can make from a given string?
For instance
with a start string of _L__R__R_ we can get
targets = L______RR, _L_R___R_, _LR_R____, etc
Is there a way we can count them like with a general formula? I would've thought this is a general sticks and bars question but since the movements are constrained in direction and a _ can essentially be shared, this really complicates that approach. How can we do this?
